# How to assign labels from DataFrame to PyTorch ImageFolder Dataset

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch

I am loading images from folder using ImageFolder, and i want to assign labels to images from DataFrame.
DataFrame contains a image name in folder and label to image

All images in folder sorted by alphabet.

My code:

```
def load_data(data_path, targets):
    train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
        root=data_path,
        transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
)
    train_data.classes = ['FAKE', 'REAL']
    train_data.class_to_idx = {k: v for k, v in zip(train_data.classes, [0, 1])}
    train_data.targets = targets
    return train_data

metadata = metadata.sort_values(by='image_name') # metadata it's my dataframe with labels
targets = np.array(metadata.label.astype('category').cat.codes)
# And i'm try to reshape my array with labels
# targets = targets.reshape(targets.shape[0], 1)
targets = torch.from_numpy(targets)

train_dataset = load_data('../input/deepfake-faces/', targets)
```

For example, in my dataset expected output of this code is should be 'Label: 1', but i'm get 0.

```
img, label = train_dataset[10]
print('Label: ', label)
plt.imshow(img.permute(1, 2, 0))
```

But, when i'm count a images with label 1, i get a correct result.

```
np.count_nonzero(train_dataset.targets == 1)
```

Comment: The label actually comes from `train_data.samples`

Comment: @Berriel thanks a lot, I missed this in source code.